# PHP Get and modify the strings certain RSS tags

Tags: php, xml, string, rss

I have a RSS feed of games. What would be the best way to extract then modify and echo the text of selected tags only from each item?

So for example the text output i would like would be:

```
Game: Rapunzel Split Up With Flynn (HTML5)
Category: girl
Image: http://www.website.com/thumb/201611/Rapunzel-Split-Up-With-Flynn.jpg
Game: Barbie Clean Place (HTML5)
Category: girl
Image: http://www.website.com/thumb/201611/Barbie-Clean-Place.jpg
```

There is many more items however as i just show 2 of many.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:trackback="http://madskills.com/public/xml/rss/module/trackback/" xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
<title>Game Feed</title> 
<link>http://www.website.com</link>
<description>Game Feed</description>
<language>en-us</language>
<atom:link href="http://website.com" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
<item>
<id>18859</id>
<name>Rapunzel Split Up With Flynn</name>
<type>html5</type>
<description>Rapunzel wants to split up with Flynn, but what the result will be, it depends on you. Can you help her find her true love during this hard period?</description>
<control>Tap on screen on mobile phone and mouse click on PC.</control>
<tags>Princess, Movie, Love, HTML5, Hidden, Girl, Disney, Cartoon, Android</tags>
<category>girl</category>
<thumb>http://www.website.com/thumb/201611/Rapunzel-Split-Up-With-Flynn.jpg</thumb>
<filetype>iframe</filetype>
<file>http://website.com/Rapunzel-Split-Up-With-Flynn/index.php?pubid=website</file>
<width>800</width>
<height>504</height>
<size>8454545</size>
<ad>1</ad>
<copyright>1</copyright>
<resize>1</resize>
<wmode_direct>0</wmode_direct>
<mobile>1</mobile>
<m_width>800</m_width>
<m_height>504</m_height>
<site>website.com</site>
<publishDate>2016-11-15</publishDate>
</item>
<item>
<id>18858</id>
<name>Barbie Clean Place</name>
<type>html5</type>
<description>Little Barbie moved to a new home, following her dad's work transfer. As a new friend, would you like to help her and build a new home for her? Very simple, clean the messy room, and then decorate it, come and try it!</description>
<control>Tap and drag to play on mobile phone and mouse click to play on PC.</control>
<tags>Room, Princess, HTML5, Girl, Educational, Design, Decorate, Cleaning, Cartoon, Barbie, Android</tags>
<category>girl</category>
<thumb>http://www.website.com/thumb/201611/Barbie-Clean-Place.jpg</thumb>
<filetype>iframe</filetype>
<file>http://website.com/Barbie-Clean-Place/index.php?pubid=website</file>
<width>800</width>
<height>504</height>
<size>4130080</size>
<ad>1</ad>
<copyright>1</copyright>
<resize>1</resize>
<wmode_direct>0</wmode_direct>
<mobile>1</mobile>
<m_width>800</m_width>
<m_height>504</m_height>
<site>website.com</site>
<publishDate>2016-11-15</publishDate>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Is there any good RSS or XML processing libs i could use or some simple code?

Comment: I use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) for RSS feeds, works quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take your xml and do json or array so you can access it easier

```
$xml = '<xmlstuff></xmlstuff'; // Be warned of ' xml could cause error

$json = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml), true);
$arrays = json_decode($json, true);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arrays);
echo "</pre>";
```

Now you can access the data like arrays!

```
echo $name1 = $arrays['channel']['item'][0]['name']."<br>";
echo $name2 = $arrays['channel']['item'][1]['name']."<br><br>";

//MORE ADVANCED

foreach ($arrays['channel']['item'] as $items){
    echo $items['name']."<br>";
}
```

i created a page here for you so you can see how it converts and is used!

http://fullertoncomputerepairwebdesign.com/tools/stackexchange/xmlparse.php

Comment: Off topic a bit now i have accepted the answer but do you know how to run a foreach loop on item without converting to json, so the regular simple xml way?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_load_string.asp would be good match, its same concept ass array but more object based so your use -> instead

Comment: $xml=simplexml_load_string($note);
echo $xml->getName() . "<br>";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
  {
  echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br>";
  }

Comment: Thanks this is useful

Comment: I try echo $xml->item . "<br>"; and foreach($xml->item->children() as $child) { however i get an error: Warning: main(): Node no longer exists. echo $xml->rss->channel->item->name doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: echo "<pre>";
foreach($xml->channel->item  as  $items){
    echo $items->name."<br>";
}
echo "</pre>";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128235/discussion-between-steven-koelsche-and-zeddex).